# Reading filenames from XML using xmlstarlet and merge them in bash

Tags: xml, perl, bash, shell, scripting

I need to read some filenames from an xml config file using xmlstarlet with an .sh script and merge contents of these files (in same order) into a single file.

Here is my xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <level1>
      ...
    </level1>

    <level2>
        <david>
            <txtfile>file1.txt</txtfile>
            <txtfile>file2.txt</txtfile>
            <txtfile>somefile.txt</txtfile>

            <incfile>config.inc</incfile>
            <incfile>foo.inc</incfile>
       </david>
       <jack>
           <txtfile>filex.txt</txtfile>
           <txtfile>filey.txt</txtfile>

           <incfile>otherconfig.inc</incfile>
           <incfile>foo1.inc</incfile>
       </jack>
    </level2>
</config>
```

After reading (maybe adding to an array in bash) these filenames using xmlstarlet i have to merge file contents into a single file using a command like

```
cat file1.txt,file2.txt,filex.txt > jack.txt
```

but i'm not sure. I don't have good skills in .sh scripting but in summary, i need to generate some merged files which including contents of above filenames like this:

```
/level2/david.txt (includes file1.txt, file2.txt, somefile.txt )
/level2/david.inc (includes config.inc, foo.inc)
/level2/jack.txt  (includes filex.txt, filey.txt)
/level2/jack.inc  (includes otherconfig.inc, foo1.inc)
```

How can i do that?

Comment: I don't understand your example.  You are mixing stuff from <david> and <jack> and storing it into jack.txt?  Parsing XML in bash doesn't seem like a good idea.  Perl or python seem like more likely suspects.

Comment: No, i don't want to mix stuff. David and Jack nodes have different .inc and .txt files. I have edited question after your comment. I want finally all .txt files of <David> node goes david.txt, all .inc files of <David> node goes david.inc etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xmlstarlet el /tmp/x.xml | sort -u | while read f; do E=""; case "$f" in */txtfile) E=".txt";; */incfile) E=".inc";; *) continue; esac; ONE=`dirname $f`; TWO=`dirname $ONE`; ONE=`basename $ONE`; TWO=`basename $TWO`; filename="/$TWO/$ONE$E"; echo "cat `xmlstarlet sel -t -c \"$f\" /tmp/x.xml |  sed -e 's|</[^>]*><[^>]*>| |g' -e 's|<[^>]*>||g'` >> $filename"; done
```

Comment: Wov! Works like a charm! it's too complex than i guessing. Thank you so much.